# Is there any hook between Nuget Powershell and Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 Extension so I can issue a Powershell commands from my extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

Let's say that i want to build a custom editor within Visual Studio.
Let say it can be an visual XML editor, a hierarchical tree editor with checkboxes or a DSL editor (with toolbox and drag and drop manipulation).
Once I am finished I want to right click on a designer surface or some button or a toolbar icon or menu item and I wantto
execute some powershell commandlets (or function) or powershell script in Nuget powershell console.

How can I access currently running this console or invoke it on demand if it is not running (and I suppose its RunspaceInvoke object). I also wish to import some modules and run some more commandlets based on my designer data or object model behind my DSL.

So is there any hook between Nuget Powershell and a VS Extension (as VSIX) or add-in?

Could I get a hold of Nuget Powershell console window and send a command via Copy commmandlet text to that window (like SendKeys)? I would prefer some live interaction with objects received by executing commands.

Comment: Why do you want to use the **NuGet** PowerShell console in particular? Can't you just run PowerShell yourself? You might want your own output pane.

Comment: Does this post here helps you? http://blog.nuget.org/20120926/invoking-nuget-services-from-inside-visual-studio.html